# I need help find the error in powershell script

Tags: powershell

Trying to get my script to work and need some help here is my code.

```
#excel
#open ap
$XL = new-object -com "Excel.Application"
$XLbooks = $XL.workbooks
$netci = [system.Globalization.CompareInfo]"en-us"
$wkbk = $XLbooks.PSBase.GetType().Invokemember("Add",[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$XLbooks,$null,$newci)
$sheet = $XLbooks.worksheets.item(1)
$sheet.name = "name"
$sheet.cells.item($row,1).formulalocal = "Fred Nurk"
$file = "c\windows\scripts\test.xlsx"
[void]$wkbk.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember("SaveAs",[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$wkbk,$file,$newci)
("Close",[Reflection.BindingFlags]::Invokemedthod,$null,$wkbk,0,$newci)
$XL.quit()
```

**Errors**:

```
Cannot convert the "en-us" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Globalization.CompareInfo".
At C:\scripts\test.ps1:5 char:44
+ $netci = [system.Globalization.CompareInfo] <<<< "en-us"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\scripts\test.ps1:7 char:34
+ $sheet = $XLbooks.worksheets.item <<<< (1)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Property 'name' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\scripts\test.ps1:8 char:8
+ $sheet. <<<< name = "name"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (name:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\scripts\test.ps1:9 char:18
+ $sheet.cells.item <<<< ($row,1).formulalocal = "Fred Nurk"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "6" argument(s): "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Jared\Document
s\c\windows\scripts\5ADD7000'. There are several possible reasons:
 The file name or path does not exist.
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook."
At C:\scripts\test.ps1:11 char:42
+ [void]$wkbk.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember <<<< ("SaveAs",[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$wkbk,$file,$n
ewci)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: what's it supposed to do?

Comment: create spread sheet and data in excel.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is kinda vague. have you tried the debugger? what happens?

Comment: "It doesn't work" may be vague, but the error messages from PowerShell that he provided are pretty specific. ;)

Comment: those were added afterwards

Answer (score 4):

The main issue you need to address is creating the CompareInfo. The first error tells you this line isn't working:

```
$netci = [system.Globalization.CompareInfo]"en-us"
```

So what you'll need to do is create the CompareInfo object this way:

```
$netci = ([system.Globalization.CultureInfo]"en-us").CompareInfo
```

Though instead of using this crazy way to create a workbook:

```
$wkbk = $XLbooks.PSBase.GetType().Invokemember("Add",[Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$XLbooks,$null,$newci)
```

...try this more sane way instead :D

```
$wkbk = $XL.workbooks.Add()
```

If you do it this way, you won't have to worry about creating the CompareInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that jumps out at me is that `$netci = [system.Globalization.CompareInfo]"en-us"` is invalid syntax. You're not calling any method on the System.Globalization.CompareInfo class, you're just placing a string after it. PowerShell is interpreting `[System.Globalization.CompareInfo]` as a typecast operator, and complains that the string "en-us" can't be converted to the data type System.Globalization.CompareInfo - because that data type doesn't exist.

You need to invoke a method that operates on "en-us". You can get a list of methods from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareinfo.aspx

Assuming that the method you want is GetCompareInfo (seems most likely to me - it returns a CompareInfo object), you'd write that line this way:

```
$netci = [System.Globalization.CompareInfo]::GetCompareInfo('en-us')
```

Note, BTW, that you have this variable as `$netci` when you create it, but as `$newci` in the rest of the script.

I haven't looked too deeply at the other errors, but they're probably a cascade effect from the failure to create $newci properly, so I suspect that if you fix this, the other errors will go away.